How to determine reliably whether code is called in a table or figure environment?
Section 8.17 of the APA style requires

In tables and figures, use an ampersand between names in both parenthetical and narrative citations.

The apa style for biblatex currently does not provide this feature. Adding a command to use an ampersand is simple, so I opened an issue to change \textcite automatically when inside a table or figure.
However, checking reliably whether we are inside a table or figure (but outside the caption) may be harder. Here is my code:
\newif\ifintable
\AddToHook{env/table/begin}{\intabletrue}
\AddToHook{env/figure/begin}{\intabletrue}
\AddToHook{cmd/@makecaption/before}{\intablefalse}
\newcommand\ifintableTF[2]{\ifintable#1\else#2\fi}

This works, but how reliably?
Which packages out there break the assumptions of my code, i.e. that proper tables and figures are defined in table and figure environments only and that captions are created via \@makecaption? The float package does at least.
In the cases of trouble with some package, do you know how to fix this?
Is there any better approach in general?
Clearly, my code does not cover tabular environments and their siblings when used outside a table. As the APA style requires captions for tables, this should be fine. But if there is some reliable way to tell whether we are in a tabular like environment, this could help as well.
Here is a MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\ifintableTF[2]{\ifintable#1\else#2\fi}
\newcommand\whereweare{\ifintableTF{inside a table}{outside any table}}
\newif\ifintable
\AddToHook{env/table/begin}{\intabletrue}
\AddToHook{env/figure/begin}{\intabletrue}
\AddToHook{cmd/@makecaption/before}{\intablefalse}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
We are \whereweare. % outside

\begin{table}
    As you see, we are \whereweare. % inside
    \caption{Our table, the caption is considered \whereweare} % outside
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Our figure, the caption is considered \whereweare} % outside
    In a figure, we are \whereweare. % inside
\end{figure}

Again, we are \whereweare. % outside
\end{document}


a longtable for example doesn't use a table environment, and its caption doesn't use \@makecaption

tabular environments are not only used for tables, but sometimes also for other layout elements. For example in article \maketitle uses a tabular for the authors.

Welcome to TeX.SE.

Some folks use center or minipage and \captionof.  You might check \@captype.

Also with the tabularray and nicematrix packages the table environment is not used to make tables.

The standard latex code uses \@captype to determine this, it expands to the float type, figure or table for example.
